# Cucumber: variable used to complete a method in ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, methods, cucumber, variable-assignment

Is there an elegant way to use the variable `var_name` in the method below - so whichever name used as a first string in the step will be reflected at the end of the `var`?

```
Then('the {string} variable in the response should be {string}') do |var_name, value|
  var = Connection.session.**"#{var_name}"**
  raise "Expected #{var} to equal '#{value}', but was #{var}" unless var == value 
end
```

BR,
Kamilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send a message with a selector you only know at runtime, you can use the [`Object#public_send`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method. `public_send` allows you to send any message to an object by just passing the name of the message as an argument:

```ruby
Connection.session.public_send(var_name)
```